# Typescript: How to check tagName in eventTarget?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Why in this case:

```
var ele = <HTMLDivElement>document.getElementById("toolbar");
    ele.addEventListener("click", function (e) { 
        if (e.target.tagName === "SPAN") { console.log(e.target.tagName) }  }, false);
```

Visual Studio shows me this error?

> Build: Operator '===' cannot be applied to types 'HTMLElement' and
>   'string'.
>
> Property 'tagName' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.

When I run a script works fine.

How to write it properly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

I would adjust that code snippet like this:

```
var ele = <HTMLDivElement>document.getElementById("toolbar");
    ele.addEventListener("click", (ev: MouseEvent) => {
        var element = ev.target as HTMLElement;     
        if (element.tagName === "SPAN") { 
            console.log(element.tagName) 
        }  
    }, false);
```

Casting the *event* property `target` to `HTMLElement` will give us all the proper properties of the underlying *element*.

Check it in [the playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=var%20ele%20%3D%20%3CHTMLDivElement%3Edocument.getElementById(%22toolbar%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20ele.addEventListener(%22click%22%2C%20(ev%3A%20MouseEvent)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%09%09var%20element%20%3D%20ev.target%20as%20HTMLElement%3B%09%09%0A%09%09%20if%20(element.tagName%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22SPAN%22)%20%7B%20%0A%09%09%09%20console.log(element.tagName)%20%0A%09%09%20%7D%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%20false)%3B)

Comment: Thank you. BTW can you recommend me good typescript tutorial?

Comment: I am really glad to see that helped ;) The starting point could be basarat and his books and videos, e.g. here https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/. In case this helped a bit, you can accept the answer ;)

Comment: what about getting tagName in ts . 
I only get lower case Instead of UpperCase.

const tagName = target.tagName as ElementType; 
    tagName === "dialog"

Answer (score 9):

I found that this syntax also works fine

```
if ((ev.target as HTMLElement).tagName === "SPAN") {
```

Answer (score 4):

In Angular if tagName property is giving error on target, try to use below code

```
event.target['tagName']
```

Comment: That's good, cause type safety doesn't get in the way and you can use it not only in Angular. BUT there is no type safety, so @Radim answer is better.

Comment: @codeepic There's no type safety in that answer either: "Like a type annotation, type assertions are removed by the compiler and won’t affect the runtime behavior of your code." https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions

Comment: True, what I meant was that by casting (I am not a big fan of casting but sometimes it's unavoidable) you tell TS explicitly what the type is, thus when you work with the type later you and TS know what to expect, hence the type safety. Once the code is transpiled to JS, as you say, type annotations and assertions will be stripped. So the safety pertains to development environment, but working with TS for the past 7 years it makes it a breeze to refactor large portions of code and know that on the type level, everything is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this type guard is helpful if you're using custom elements.

```
function hasTagName<K extends keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap>(
    el: Element|EventTarget|null, tagName: K): el is HTMLElementTagNameMap[K] {
  return el instanceof HTMLElement && el.tagName.toLowerCase() === tagName;
}

function({target}: Event) {
  if (hasTagName(target, 'paper-radio')) {
    // target has the right type
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

two equal signs compares values between(int == 'string') types (i.e. 19=='19') evals to true.

3 equal signs is when comparing values and types. So you're comparing a string type to an HTML type. Thus equalling falsy. If you want to compare the tagname element to a string use two equal signs